# MacOS Big Sur Spotlight

Tags: macos, spotlight, big-sur

I have a small issue with macOS's spotlight. When I hit command + spacebar, it shows me Spotlights window as usually then I start typing the name of eg. application. Spotlight shows an application but without a list of recent documents(its called quick preview, I think). The same problem occurs while searching for contacts, photos, etc. Not sure if it is a bug or wrong setting.

here is a short video.:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Px9.jpg

Comment: In System preferences > Spotlight make sure everything you want displayed in the search list is checked. Also note that it takes a day or two for Spotlight to re-index the drive after an OS install/Upgrade. You may notice your Mac getting warmer and/or the fans running more. This is normal.

Comment: I would like an answer on this also. Currently spotlight is not showing me any results. I have everything turned on in preferences. I'm using Big Sur on the M1 chip